# php xdebug при остановке stop дебага, скрипт работает дальше

Tags: php, xdebug

Как отловить, что я остановил дебаг и завершить скрипт?

скрипт имеет бесконечный while цикл

```
<?
$stop = false;
while (!$stop) {
  // код...
}
?>
```

как мне отловить, что я закончил дебаг, что xdebug завершил отладку, стой..
потому как если я нажму на стоп, скрипт не завершается, приходится через диспетчер его убивать.

Comment: Так а зачем тут бесконечный цикл изначально?

Comment: У ide есть кнопка остановить, которая в принципе стопорит скрипт

Comment: Как оказалось не стопорит.

Comment: Ну мне нужен бесконечный цикл, у меня демон, скрипт обрабатывает задачи